# How to determine if a File has finished downloading

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I download GB's of stuff every day. And I get all OCD and organize files and folders so many times during the day and it's driving me nuts.

So I plan on writing an app that detects when a file has finished downloading (to the Windows Downloads folder), and then places it in its relevant categorized folder.

E.g.:
I download an app. When the app detects that the file has finished downloading, it places it into Sub-folder *Applciations*. Or, when I finish downloading a Document, the document is then placed inside the *Documents* sub-folder of the Downloads folder.

The problem I have here is that I don't want to do this unless there is a definitive way to tell whether a file has finished downloading.

Things I have thought of:

1. I have thought about implementing FileSystemWatcher on the Downloads folder, and when a new file is created there, it gets added to a list. And when FileSystemWatcher detects that the file size has changed, or has been modified, it will start a timer; the purpose of this timer is to determine *after **x** amount of seconds* whether the download is complete. It does this by assuming (wrongly) that if a file's size has not increased in a specified period of time, the download is complete.

That's all I can think of. Any ideas on how this kind of thing can be accomplished?

Comment: Some "download manager" tools hook into the browser via a plugin model and allow you to do rule-based filtering on the downloads.

Comment: I totally forgot about those features, @ravuya. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File is blocked when it is accessed. Not every file. But you could check whether the file is open by another application. If the file is not open - this should tell you, that it has downloaded completely.